Rectangular Billiard Table
Given a rectangle of length $1$ and height $h \gt 1$. For
which angles $\theta$ does a trajectory (which does not hit a corner) get arbitrarily close to any point on the boundary of the table?
I think the answer is irrational multiples of $\pi$. However, I don't know how to prove it.
Thank you for your time.

I suppose rectangle can be assumed to be $[0,1]\times[0,h]$ and initial trajectory point is $(0,0)$ with angle $\theta$ usual from x-axis ? I wonder if we can unfold the rectangle to upper quadrant and transform the condition for instance to straight line arbitrary close to lattice  points which is a classic (uses $|x-\frac pq|<\frac 1q$). This is because  billard reflexions unfold to a straight line.

Can you please elaborate your question more? Maybe I am dumb, but I have trouble understanding what exactly is the problem even asking...Can you please also define what do you mean by "trajectory"? And, by "height" did you mean "breadth"? And what is the starting point exactly?

The correct answer is actually if $\theta$ is of the form $arctan(x h)$ where $x$ is irrational. (Assuming you start at (0,0))
This is really about an adequate use of Kronecker's approximation theorem.
A fun fact is that the trajectory will get as close as you want to any point of the rectangle if and only if it will not meet any corner.
